# ITextSharp 4.1.6. PDF Table - how to remove whitespace on top of each cell? [padding and leading already set to 0]

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, cellpadding

I'm having a problem with ITextSharp's tables. I'd like to have cells without top & bottom padding, so that they are placed closer to each other.

Although I have set the padding and the leading of the cell to 0, the white-space still remains.

[image: See the screen]

Does anyone please know how to remove the whitespace ?

EDIT:

Thanx to prompt answer from Dylan, I've managed to resolve my issue. Here's the source snippet if someone gets across similar issue

```
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 5, 5, 10, 10);
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("C:\\Users\\brum\\Desktop\\untitled.pdf", FileMode.Create))
        {
            iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs);
            document.Open();
            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Spanning 2 cols"));

            cell.Colspan = 2;
            cell.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
            cell.Padding = 0f;
            cell.UseAscender = true;
            table.AddCell(cell);

            table.AddCell("Next row 1");
            table.AddCell("Next row 2");

            document.Add(table);
            document.Close();
        }
```

`cell.UseAscender = true; // This is the line that did the trick for me`

Comment: Oh my God!... :D I was going crazy with this top white space in each cell. The vertical alignment was not working correctly due to this.

Comment: For future reference, this is also stated in the iTextSharp docs, eg: http://www.afterlogic.com/mailbee-net/docs-itextsharp/html/0602b79e-ea9c-0c7d-c4b2-bc4b5f976f15.htm

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Set the top padding to something small or even negative. Another option is 
`PdfPCell.setUseAscender()`.

ex:

```
cell.setPaddingTop(0f);  // No padding on top cell
```

or

```
cell.UseAscender = true;
```

Please paste the code you have.

Comment: Worked for me too, been trying to work this out for hours - good question, great answer!

Comment: @bigtv - I was in the same boat... but as always our heavenly father brought me to the right spot. Great answer Dylan.

Comment: UseAscender works.  This library makes me want to jump into the sun.